# Javascript calculate percentage consistency of an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, percentage

I am trying to calculate the consistency of an array of values which output a percentage. So for example an array of [1,1,1,1,1] would output 100% consistency, and array of [1,12,23,5,2] would output something like 25% consistency.

I have tried a simple percentage difference calculation but is only for two numbers whereas this needs to work for a dynamic array and this only outputs the difference. Any help would be appreciated so thanks in advance.

```
function getPercentage(n1, n2){
   var newValue = n1 - n2;
   return (newValue / n1) * 100;
}
getPercentage(1, 12)
```

Comment: *array of [1,12,23,5,2] would output something like 25% consistency.*  Can you explain the calculation behind 25%?

Comment: Hi, that was just a guessed value as an example, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: In that case what do you need help with?

Comment: I need to calculate a percentage of consistency between any array of values. So if an array contained [1,5,8,12,2,18] what would be the consistency across all of those values? i.e if the array was [2,2,2,2,2,2] it would be 100% consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I refined the base value used in calculating the overall consistency between members of the array.

The new results calculated (which on visual inspection seems plausible, again it depends on the definition of consistency over all members but I think this is getting closer):

```
$ node jsscratch.js
Consistency for 1,1,1,1,1 is 100.000% fixed to 3 decimal places
Consistency for 1,12,23,5,2 is 33.360% fixed to 3 decimal places
Consistency for 1,12,23,15,12 is 50.160% fixed to 3 decimal places
Consistency for 1,2,10 is 83.778% fixed to 3 decimal places

/**
 * Calculate the expected value
 */
 function expectancy(arrayOfValues) {
    let sumTotal = function(previousValue, currentValue) { 
                         return previousValue + currentValue; 
                   };
    let u = arrayOfValues.reduce(sumTotal);
    // Assume each member carries an equal weight in expected value
    u = u / arrayOfValues.length;
    return u;
 }

 /**
  * Calculate consistency of the members in the vector
  * @param {Array<number>} The vector of members to inspect for similarity
  * @return {number} The percentage of members that are the same
  */
  var similarity = function(arrayOfValues) {
     let sumTotal = function(previousValue, currentValue) { 
                              return previousValue + currentValue; 
                    };
     // Step 1: Calculate the mean value u
     let u = expectancy(arrayOfValues); // Calculate the average
     // Step 2: Calculate the standard deviation sig
     let sig = [];
     let N = 1/arrayOfValues.length;

     for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfValues.length; i++) {
       sig.push(N*(arrayOfValues[i] - u) * (arrayOfValues[i] - u));
     }
     // This only works in mutable type, such as found in JavaScript, else sum it up
     sig = sig.reduce(sumTotal);
     // Step 3: Offset from 100% to get the similarity
     return 100 - sig;
    }

    answer = similarity(ar1);
    console.log(`Consistency for ${ar1} is ${answer.toFixed(3)}% fixed to 3 decimal places`);

    answer = similarity(ar2);
    console.log(`Consistency for ${ar2} is ${answer.toFixed(3)}% fixed to 3 decimal places`);

    answer = similarity(ar3);
    console.log(`Consistency for ${ar3} is ${answer.toFixed(3)}% fixed to 3 decimal places`);

    answer = similarity(ar4);
    console.log(`Consistency for ${ar4} is ${answer.toFixed(3)}% fixed to 3 decimal places`);
```

Comment: If consistenct is quantifiably describe as the correlation between all members then the above rollup phase of the algorithm would need slight adjustment.

Comment: Yep this is much closer thanks, I guess the definition of consistency is difficult and would be based on all members as the array changes and grows. So if the array was:

[1] output = 100%
[1,1] = 100%
[1,2] = 50%
[1,2,10] = ? (I'm guessing 25% or lower?!)

Comment: If I may ask whats the application of this that you're trying to solve? A high level concept would perhaps lead to reasoning a better math model for it, the actual algorithm is straightforward to design once the model for converting the high level concept to quantifiable format has been derived from the qualified concept (the high level concept)...

Comment: Hi Marius, it is simply a statistic on a collection of scores as the competition goes on. So if the scores were very close together the statistical percentage would be higher, if not then the percentage is lower.

Comment: Hey @dbach in that case it's more a correlation algorithm you're looking for. Therefore the second revised algo is close but not correct. Example: [1, 12, 23, 15, 12] should be in the ball park range of 3 members are really close out of the 5 so an answer close to 60% would be expected...

Comment: Ok, I will keep working at it and thanks for your help...enjoy the wine!

Comment: So it involves a similar algo as above but first calculating each member's standard deviation (because there's n members and not two, x and y) - keeping these values in a list for later use. Then calculating the correlation using the members and the standard deviations will give the correctness.

Comment: Cool dude, see my last comment, use the last algo as a basis but calculate the standard deviation of each stored in an array, then use the deviations in calculating the correlation, this will then give the answer you're looking for...initially (depending on how deep you wanna go into the different correlation concepts) - but should be accurate enough.

Comment: sorry not sure I fully understand https://jsfiddle.net/ltbmedia/9Ls12odu/ the result is not correct?

Comment: hey @dbach See the second revised algo above this comment, this should work for what you're looking for. Yeah I mis-spoke in terms of correlation, not suitable for this scenario...

Comment: Ah cool, sorry missed the revised version! That's spot on, thanks for all of your help, have a good weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is my first stab I'll take at it, tried to brake it up into smaller units of code to make it easier to work through. If I had enough time this could be further refined but then the readability goes south ;-)

Tried to avoid using TypeScript and to keep it as ECMAScript 5 friendly as possible. (Sorry about the messy formatting)

```
let ar100 = [1,1,1,1,1];
let ar25 = [1,12,23,5,2];

/**
 * Calculate the lack of difference between two values (ie consistency)
 * @param {number} valA
 * @param {number} valB
 * @returns {number} The consistency as a decimal
 *                  where 1 is '100% consistent'
 *                  and 0.5 is '50% consistent'
 */
var calcConsistency = function( valA, valB) {
    let diff = Math.abs(valA - valB);
    let consistency = (valA - diff) / valA;
    // assumption: you can't be less than zero consistent
    return consistency < 0 ? 0 : consistency;
}

/**
 * A predicate used by the map operation in 'overallConsistency'
 * @param {*} val
 * @param {*} index
 * @param {*} values
 * @return {number} the average consistency of the current 'val' to the other 'values'
 */
var mapEachConsistency = function(val, index, values) {
    let predicateGetOnlyOthers = function(currentValue, othersIndex) {
                                        return index !== othersIndex;
                                };

    let others = values.filter(predicateGetOnlyOthers);
    const otherCount = others.length;
    let totalConsistency = others.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue) {
        return previousValue + calcConsistency(val, currentValue);
    });
    return (totalConsistency / otherCount);
}

/**
 * Calculate the overall average consistency of an array of numbers
 * @param {Array<number>} arrayOfValues
 * @return {number} The average consistency score as percentage
 */
var overallConsistency = function(arrayOfValues) {
    let consists = arrayOfValues.map(mapEachConsistency);

    let sumTotal = function(previous, current){ return previous + current; };

    let avgAnswer = consists.reduce(sumTotal);
    return (avgAnswer / consists.length) * 100;
};

// Here's using it to see the results
var answer = overallConsistency(ar100);
    console.log(`Consistency: ${answer.toFixed(3)}% (fixed to 3 dicimal place)`);

    answer = overallConsistency(ar25);
    console.log(`Consistency: ${answer.toFixed(3)}% (fixed to 3 dicimal place)`);
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez I don't think Marius has a question as he's giving his version of a solution to the person's question.

Comment: @Matt Ooops - my bad :-) Sorry for that.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for your solution. I need to work from just one array [1,12,23,15,12], so the comparison is just each value against the other. The array of [1,1,1,1,1] was just to show that it would output 100% consistency. 

Currently the array of [1,12,23,15,12] outputs '117.145%' but should be less of a percentage as the numbers are not very consistent with each other.

Hope this helps and thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey @dbach that's right the above example tests two example arrays. I made some assumptions on what the consistency is defined as... I think it's a starting point (it can be rolled up into a series of map+reduce calls once the prototype is correct). The new example leading to non normalized answer would indicate the rolling up stage of the maths is incorrect. Perhaps using the final normalization total as a more numerically meaningful base value will fix it)...

Comment: Hang on (a good glass of red made me realize something): @dbach I think I'm trying to find similarity and you may be looking to find percentage of members that are the same (that are consistent, my second solution is better for that), is that actually what you're looking for (percentage the same)? If so then its a much simpler algo...

Comment: Yep I think I might need a glass of red as well!

Comment: lol it helps me in avoiding analysis paralysis ;-) Like I said on your other comment below, then you want to look at calculating statistical correlation between members, that will give the answer you're looking for.